# Conversion from Objective-C to C#

Tags: c#, objective-c, macos, cocoa

Converting Obj-C code to Xamarin C#

How do I convert this code to C#?

```
[browser setCellClass:[CustomBrowserCell class]];
```

I tried but do not understand what is factory Id here?

```
_browser.SetCellClass(CustomBrowserCell.Class);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unsure what the question/problem is here

> what is factory Id here?

`factoryId` is the identifier used as the name of the parameter, similar to most programming languages. The declaration in Objective-C is:

```
- (void)setCellClass:(Class)factoryId;
```

The Xamarin declaration is:

```
public virtual void SetCellClass (ObjCRuntime.Class factoryId);
```

Does that answer your question?